# Search specified string inside textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i have textbox with text:

```
1234 YYMM 1057316895 12, AB 6386 ABC
```

where YYMM is in this case Year and Month. What i'd like to do is to search if in this textbox exist YYMM, and highlight this part of text, or somehow show that in this specified textbox exist not fully completed field.

So when i rewrite this string with 1203 instead of YYMM error will not be received.

And! This YYMM can be in any place of string in textbox, so i can't do something like

```
if (textbox1.Text.Substring(x,4)=="YYMM) {}
```

where x is index of YYMM location.

Tnx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here a sample pseudocode that can help you; (Put in your validating event)

```
int pos = textbox1.Text.IndexOf("YYMM");
if(pos != -1)
{ 
    textbox1.SelectionStart = pos;
    textbox1.SelectionLength = 4;
    // MessageBox("Error");
}
```

Comment: Add textbox1.ScrollToCaret() to show the found text.

Comment: ...and in the textbox properties, set HideSelection = false;

Answer (score 5):

This will assign the start index and the length of the selection, but it will not make it visible. To ensure visibility, I would recommend to add

```
textbox1.ScrollToCaret();
textbox1.HideSelection = false;
```